# Amazon.in site language setting radio button handling in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, radio-button

I am new to selenium automation and while learning radio button handling in selenium, I tried to automate language setting in amazon.in page. I am unable to select the radio button listed in the page.

site: https://www.amazon.in/customer-preferences/edit?ie=UTF8&preferencesReturnUrl=%2F&ref_=topnav_lang

code used: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'ta_IN']")).click(); (I tried to select the language tamil- TA (3rd radio button)). Can anyone guide me in this?

```
public class seleniumTutorial2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/customer-preferences/edit?ie=UTF8&preferencesReturnUrl=%2F&ref_=topnav_lang");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'ta_IN']")).click();
        
        
    }

}

'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this xpath://span[text() = 'TA']

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'TA']")).click();

Comment: How to click the radio button when it can be done only by clicking the radiobutton icon instead of the text. Could be please explain it with the example given below. Please select the option Radio5 in the given link: http://test.rubywatir.com/radios.php. Please help. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to click on *//input[@value = 'ta_IN']/following-sibling::i*